# Olark javascript customization with rails postgresql database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Olark chat, a javascript widget, allows customization.  For a signed-in user, I am trying to pull data from our postgresql database.  The site is built with rails and we're testing with Chrome.

This code passes the WORDS 'User Name', 'User Email', and 'User Phone Number' to Olark's dashboard:

```
olark('api.visitor.updateFullName', {
  fullName: 'User Name'
});
olark('api.visitor.updateEmailAddress', {
  emailAddress: 'User Email'
});
olark('api.visitor.updatePhoneNumber', {
  phoneNumber: 'User Phone Number'
});
```

I believe this code should work; however, it's not (and the page with the chat widget won't load).  So, I assume a syntax error?:

```
olark('api.visitor.updateFullName', {
  fullName: '<%= j @user.name.html_safe %>'
});
olark('api.visitor.updateEmailAddress', {
  emailAddress: '<%= j @user.email.html_safe %>'
});
olark('api.visitor.updatePhoneNumber', {
  phoneNumber: '<%= j @user.user_phone.html_safe %>'
});
```

So, I tried passing the data into Olark.  This approach didn't work either (and, again, the page with the chat widget won't load).

Outside the `<script` tag:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "user", data: {email: @current_user.email} do %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Inside the `<script>` tag, where the custom code goes:

```
olark('api.visitor.updateFullName', {
  fullName: $('.user').data('email');
});
... etc. ...
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What output do you have in the developers' console when you try this? Also, have you tried putting the first calls (without the server-side interpolation) into the console directly to check?

Just to be clear, your syntax looks fine. I suspect namespacing or a general script problem, but console output would help narrow it down.

Comment: @A.Wison Please answer the question by stating that 'your syntax looks fine' and I'll accept it in order to help the next person (and you'll get credit).  The only RoR / Olark q&a on SO is this one: 18499914/installing-olark-in-ruby-on-rails  I followed Sung Won Cho's advice and placed the Olark code in a partial.  Now, why wasn't the code working.  I hadn't added `phony_normalize :user_phone, default_country_code: 'US'` to phony.rb and hadn't added the `:user_phone` attribute to the application and user controllers.  It's now working.  Thanks again for responding and helping me.  Doug

Comment: @A. Wilson - please see above.  Perhaps, I need a space between the A. and W...

Comment: Oh hey, maybe, although it looks like you also missed an "l". Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned this in the comments to your question, but just for reference for future visitors, that syntax looks fine on the front-end. For visibility to anyone coming later, the root cause ended up being not creating some setup to make the user_phone attribute available to the application at the level he was using it (see [Olark javascript customization with rails postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643663/olark-javascript-customization-with-rails-postgresql-database?noredirect=1#comment62813717_37643663) for details)

Comment: Thanks again!  Doug